# oci_parse() expects parameter 1 to be resource / ociexecute() [function.ociexecute]: ORA-00904

Tags: php, parsing, oracle-call-interface

I've recently been working on a uni assignment and had a lot of trouble getting my code to work.

The errors that seem to occur when I upload my .php file onto the server and then try to view them are the following:

1. Warning: oci_parse() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /home/contactusphp.php on line 227
2. Warning: ociexecute() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/contactusphp.php on line 232
   Your mesage has been sent successfully!

Additional details:
This is for use in an Oracle database, and the original purpose was for a user to use a contact form to send a message to the site owner (putting the message into the database).

My code is as follows:

```
211. <?
212.        // extract form data 
213.        $emailcontact = $_REQUEST['emailcontact'] ;
214.        $email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'] ;
215.        
216.        // Create the SQL statement to add data into the database 
217.        $sql = "INSERT INTO contactus (emailcontact, email_address) VALUES ('$emailcontact', '$email_address')";
218.        
219.        // Set the oracle user login and password info
220.        $dbuser = 'XXXX';
221.        $dbpass = 'XXXX';
222.        $db = 'SSID';
223.        $connect = 'OCI_Logon($dbuser, $dbpass, $db)';
224.        
225.        
226.        // Add this data into the database as a new record
227.        $stmt = OCI_Parse($connect, $sql);
228.        if(!stmt) {
229.                echo 'An error occurred in parsing the SQL string./n';
230.                exit;
231.        }
232.        OCI_Execute($stmt); {
233.                echo ('Your mesage has been sent successfully!'); 
234.    } 
235. ?>
```

I can't seem to find what could be wrong, and I'm not very experienced with web development either.

EDIT: I got rid of quotes, and changed OCI_Logon/OCI_Parse/OCI_Execute to OCILogon, etc.
However, the problem changed when I did so.

There's a new error code, which is as follows:

> Warning: ociexecute() [function.ociexecute]: ORA-00904: "EMAILCONTACT": invalid identifier in /home/contactusphp.php on line 232

The new code is:

```
211. <?
212.        // extract form data 
213.        $emailcontact = $_REQUEST['emailcontact'] ;
214.        $email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'] ;
215.        
216.        // Create the SQL statement to add data into the database 
217.        $sql = "INSERT INTO contactus (emailcontact, email_address) VALUES ('$emailcontact', '$email_address')";
218.        
219.        // Set the oracle user login and password info
220.        $dbuser = 'XXXX';
221.        $dbpass = 'XXXX';
222.        $db = 'SSID';
223.        $connect = OCILogon($dbuser, $dbpass, $db);
224.        
225.        
226.        // Add this data into the database as a new record
227.        $stmt = OCIParse($connect, $sql);
228.        if(!stmt) {
229.                echo 'An error occurred in parsing the SQL string./n';
230.                exit;
231.        }
232.        OCIExecute($stmt); {
233.                echo ('Your mesage has been sent successfully!'); 
234.    } 
235. ?>
```

EDIT:
The problem ended up fixing itself, and I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

Why the quotes around this function?

```
$connect = 'OCI_Logon($dbuser, $dbpass, $db)';
```

Comment: That's what we were taught to do in classes, basically.

Comment: You don't put quotes around a statement which calls a function to be executed, quotes are for strings.